# Two public method calls a private method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit

I heard some one said that it's better to write Junit test for a private method via a public method. But in this case, I should test private method to avoid the duplicated code. Is it good approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is a mix of subjective taste, best practice I've picked up and gut feeling.

For unit tests I don't mind calling private functions directly, if you by unit testing mean test a specific function and nothing else. I don't mind because it cuts down on wrapper code and it's likely that function usage patterns might be rather unusual compared to production code.

If the testing goes further than that, a whole class or a range of functions, I prefer to only use public methods since that's how other code will be using it.

Comment: You meant a clear verification is more valuable than a duplicated code  in Junit test ?

Comment: I'm trying to say that it depends on what you're testing and how.

Answer (score 0):

So, yes you can and a lot of people do test what would normally be `private` methods in this way. Generally the method is changed to default scope and I recommend adding the `@VisibleForTesting` annotation provided by `Guava`.

The problem with this approach is that it does not allow for (or limits the ability of) the code under test to be refactored. A good unit test allows the entire class under test to be completely refactored (while maintaining the same API) without the test failing.

So there is a balance here. Since both `public` method have the same set of requirements regarding what is happening in the `private` method it is good practice to fully exercise this set of requirements for each public method.

My suggestion (depending on and balanced by the complexity of the `private` method) is to create a utility method in your test that configures the private method (sets it up to behave a particular way) and use this method in the tests of the public methods. Do the same for a verify method.

Another option is to create tests that test the `private` method's functionality and pass in a reflection `Method` as the entry point. This would allow you to test all functionality via both public methods without repeated code.

Comment: I think your solution is good. SHould create a sub testing method, and when running testing method, call sub testing method. So the test will go through most cases. +1